# "Seen" updated with JavaScript not matching with "seen" after refreshing profile page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

When I open someone else's profile page and remain on it for a few minutes, I see a certain number of time in "seen" field that has been passed with JavaScript. But when I refresh the page, the "seen" time is much less. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

The profile pages are cached, so when re-fetching you see the cached version.

Comment: But refresh at each time varies, and a significant difference in time - from 3 to 7 minutes.

Comment: It seemed to me that the cache store user exit time from site, and then there is a miscalculation on the field.

Comment: @maximkou - We cache for 10 minutes. And we use the last time they did anything on the site.

Comment: It's always caching.